# Non-integral common denominator

Tags: number-theory, numerical-value

I have a list `r = {114.49, 311.876, 538.704}` whose elements are multiples of a non-integer value. I want to find the common denominator `k` satisfying `r = k n` where each element of `n` is the sum of squares of three integers that are all even or all odd. But error can be tolerated to some degree as `r` itself is not exact.

My first attempt

```
Rationalize[#, 0.01] & /@ (r/First@r)
(* {1, 19/7, 33/7} *)
```

Changing the tolerance will change the end result but none of them satisfied my criterion.

My second attempt (sort of like the Euclidean algorithm)

```
Sort@Nest[DeleteDuplicates[
 Join[Abs[Subtract @@ # & /@ Subsets[#, {2}]], #], 
 Abs[#1 - #2] < 5. &] &, r, 4]
{*24.0098, 29.4429, 53.4527, 61.0373, 85.0471, 90.4802, 114.49, \
  136.348, 143.933, 167.943, 175.527, 197.386, 204.97, 226.829, \
  250.838, 258.423, 280.281, 287.866, 311.876, 341.319, 365.328, \
  372.913, 394.771, 402.356, 426.366, 455.809, 479.818, 485.251, \
  509.261, 538.704*}
```

But I think the error piled up after each subtraction that `24.0098` is not really a common denominator.

So what else can I do?

P.S. I listed the first 50 possible values of `n` below, just for the reference

```
{3, 4, 8, 11, 12, 16, 19, 20, 24, 27, 32, 35, 36, 40, 43, 44, 48, 51, \
52, 56, 59, 64, 67, 68, 72, 75, 76, 80, 83, 84, 88, 91, 96, 99, 100, \
104, 107, 108, 115, 116, 120, 123, 128, 131, 132, 136, 139, 140, 144, \
147}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like the Millikan experiment:)

```
r = {114.49, 311.876, 538.704}; 
even = Select[Tr /@ Tuples[Range[0, 100, 2]^2, 3] // Union, 0 < # < 538 &];
odd =  Select[Tr /@ Tuples[Range[1, 100, 2]^2, 3] // Union, # < 538 &];
alleven = Subsets[even, {3}];
allodd  = Subsets[odd, {3}];

Min@(Variance[r/#] & /@ alleven)
(* 7.26497*10^-6 *)

Min@(Variance[r/#] & /@ allodd)
(* 0.0000239237 *)
```

Then it's an even combination.

```
or = First@Ordering@(Variance[r/#] & /@ alleven);
alleven[[or]]
(* {100, 272, 472} *)
```

and

```
r/alleven[[or]]
(* {1.1449, 1.1466, 1.14132} *)
```

So we can find your best `k` as:

```
Minimize[Norm[k alleven[[or]] - r], k]
(* {1.26427, {k -> 1.14271}} *)
```

Comment: Millikin was using number theory albeit not overtly (simultaneous diophantine approximation), but fortunately did not also have sums of three squares to contend with.

Comment: @DanielLichtblau I remember trying to follow those nasty oil drops on the microscope . No fun nor dophantine problems there :)